# How to make bootstrap dropdown searchable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There are many items to be shown (>100) in one of my [bootstrap dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) lists. How can I add a search functionality for that list, so that user can type in a some keyword, click search button, and the list brings out only the relevant items? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this demo? http://www.bootply.com/69994

Comment: Thanks @ChongTang this is a nice one, but it doesn't work if the search term starts from in the middle of a word.

Comment: BTW, if you are using Angular JS. This is a pretty good plugin which I used before. http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this lovely [library](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) . Setting `data-live-search="true"` is all I need.